# Unity 3D and Protobuf-net: NullReferenceException when assigning value to an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, protobuf-net

My proto file works fine in python. However when I try to use protogen to generate a cs file for protobuf-net, it gives me an error message NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Here is my proto file

```
message Request {
    enum Type {
        CREDENTIALS             = 0; // user credentials
    }

    // user credentials message 
    message CredentialsData {
        required string login = 1;
        required string password = 2;
    }

    required Type                      type                         = 1;
    optional CredentialsData           credentials_data             = 2;}
```

Where it is called in Unity 3D

```
void Start () 
    {
        Request request = new Request ();
        request.type = Request.Type.CREDENTIALS;
        request.credentials_data.login = "admin";
    }
```

When assigning request.type = Request.Type.CREDENTIALS, it has no problem. But the next line gives me that error message. Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect `request.credentials_data` is `null`. That is simple to fix:

```
request.credentials_data = new CredentialsData();
```

or perhaps even use an object-initializer for the entire thing:

```
   var request = new Request {
       type = Request.Type.CREDENTIALS,
       credentials_data = new CredentialsData {
           login = "admin"
       }
   };
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks Marc. I also have problem finding the documentation for protobuf-net. Can you give me some suggestions?